# Ask about cancel method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

According to document [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns

However, in my case onCancelled(Object) is called right after I call cancel method. My question: Is the document wrong?

Answer (score 0):

An `AsyncTask` executing normally can be in four states: not yet executed, executing, finished, and canceled.  The `cancel()` method does not work if the task is already finished or canceled.  If the task is executing, `doInBackground()` will have to complete before `onCancelled()` is called.  However, if the task has not started executing, `onCancelled()` will be called right away and you will not be able to execute the task.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply.My case is not same as your opion. The doInbackground started. It count 1-10 in 10s. When it counts to 5 I call cancel. The log show onCancelled called. However, doInbackground task continues to 10. Now it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I experineced the similar problem. After calling cancel() my task continued to run. That was valid for Android 2.2 and 2.3. I ended up with checking regularly isCancelled() inside doInBackground. And the behavior was the same either you call cancel(true) or cancel(false).